# How to select value from table with current date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to pull the value from the 'dwgm_10am_final_price' column with today's current date (2021-01-06). In this case it will be null until a value is inserted into the table at 10am. as depicted in the image below.

[image: Table]

This is the current query I am trying but it is returning 'No Data' on my Grafana dashboard. How can I edit my query to always pull the data with today's timestamp, regardless of it is NULL or a numerical value.

```
SELECT gas_date AS time, dwgm_10am_final_price
FROM gas_market_prices 
WHERE DATE('time') = CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get a date from the **String** `time`, which doesn't exist

You need to use backticks for your query

```
SELECT gas_date AS time, dwgm_10am_final_price
FROM gas_market_prices 
WHERE DATE(`time`) = CURDATE()
```

You can read this canonical thread [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)